# How to manually link libraries in react-native versions > 0.60?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

RN version >0.60 supports  auto linking but there are some npms which can only be linked manually e.g. react-native-payapal-wrapper. Whenever I link it manually it shows me some React/RCTxyz.h(RCTBridgeModulle.h , RCTAnimationType.h, RCTDefine.h etc) file missing and when I link XYX.xcodewproj manually to libraries it start giving  other errors. How to fix it?